GetX obx not working, even after using reactive values and dependency injection
I am creating an app to upload images, and using file_picker extension for selecting local files. I am trying to show two different widgets based on if file has been picked or not. I am using Obx for that purpose, but somehow it's not working.
My code is shown below:
import 'package:facesearch_app/controller/image_controller.dart';
import 'package:facesearch_app/widgets/after_image_upload.dart';
import 'package:facesearch_app/widgets/upload_section.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../constants/colors.dart';

class UploadScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final ImageController imageController = Get.put(ImageController());

UploadScreen({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 70,
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.scaffoldBg,
      title: const Text(
        'Upload',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Pacifico'),
      ),
    ),
    backgroundColor: CustomColors.scaffoldBg,
    body: Obx(() => imageController.isPicked.value
        ? const AfterImageUpload()
        : const UploadSection()));
 }
}

For the controller file,
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ImageController extends GetxController {
 RxBool isPicked = false.obs;

getImages() async {
 FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'svg', 'png', 'jpeg']);
  try {
  if (result != null) {
    isPicked.value = true;
  }
  } catch (e) {
  print(e);
 } 
 }
 }

After Image Upload code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../constants/colors.dart';

class AfterImageUpload extends StatelessWidget {
const AfterImageUpload({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'You have selected files.',
          style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
       Text(
        'Tap elsewhere to select more files.',
        style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
            color: CustomColors.scaffoldLight, fontSize: 20),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("SUBMIT",
              style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuCondensed(
                fontSize: 20,
              )))
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}

Upload Section Code:
import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
import 'package:facesearch_app/controller/image_controller.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:iconly/iconly.dart';

import '../constants/colors.dart';

class UploadSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadSection({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Center(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      ImageController().getImages();
    },
    child: DottedBorder(
      color: CustomColors.scaffoldLight,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: const Radius.circular(20),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: size.height * 0.25,
        width: size.width * 0.6,
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              IconlyBold.plus,
              color: CustomColors.scaffoldLight,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.02,
            ),
            Text(
              "Upload any picture..",
              style: GoogleFonts.oswald(
                color: CustomColors.scaffoldLight,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
 }

Please guide me if any solution available.

can you edit your answer and show me AfterImageUpload() because Obx should wrapped at specific widget which you want to update the state of it.

Yeah I have added the part.

you need to wrap exactly widget that you want to update with obx
